# How is scrollView page size calculated?

Tags: swift

I have a scrollView embedded inside a UIView with a top constraint to the navigation bar.
My question is, how is the page size calculated of a UIScrollView (where scrollView.pagingEnabled = true)? I want each page to be the size of the aforementioned UIView, but it turns out that it's slightly bigger.

[image: scrollView]

I set the contentSize as so in the view controller:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 64) * 4)
```

I figured each page size would be UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 64 (because of the navigation bar and clock) but, like I said, the page turns out to be slightly bigger.

Comment: What does slightly bigger mean? Give us numbers, please :)

Comment: @Cristik the size of each page that I can "flick" through in the scrollView is bigger than the desired size (UIScreen.mainScreen().bound.height - 64). I have no idea on how to calculate the page size that's currently being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height of the scrollView same as UIView that hosts it `self.scrollView.superview`.

Edit:
The 'slightly bigger' is probably the 64 points offset. You need to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` inside yout viewController that hosts the scrollView to fix it

Comment: I did both programmatically and in the storyboard

Comment: Then it should work properly because the page size is equal to the bounds of the UIScrollView.